# PHP do loop doesnt exit

Tags: php, do-loops

I have made a small script, which should redirect to one of 8 pages by random. Before picking the page I ask the database, to narrow the choices. (So that every page is picked on the same seed) .
Unfortunatly I got stuck in the do-while loop. 
Here is the code:

```
 <?php
$surveys = array(
    1 => "711275", 
    2 => "488985", 
    3 => "515385",
    4 => "467411",
    5 => "755429",
    6 => "335888",
    7 => "673921",
    8 => "532261");
$surveysCount = array(
    1 => 0, 
    2 => 0, 
    3 => 0,
    4 => 0,
    5 => 0,
    6 => 0,
    7 => 0,
    8 => 0);
$path = 'http://www.unet.univie.ac.at/~a0106191/index.php/';
$pathPostfix = '/lang-de';  

$user = 'xxxx';
$pass = 'xxxx';
$host = 'xxxx'; 

// establish database connection
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die('Cannot connect to Database - Please try later!');

mysql_select_db('a0106191', $conn) or die('Cannot connect to Database - Please try later!');

foreach ($surveys as $nr=>$survey) {
    $stmt = 'SELECT submitdate FROM lime_survey_'.$survey.' WHERE submitdate IS NOT NULL';
    //echo $stmt.'<br/>';
    if($res = mysql_query($stmt)) {
        if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
            $surveysCount[$nr] = mysql_num_rows($res);
        }
    }

    //echo $surveysCount[$nr].'<br/>';
}
$selection = array();
$counter = 0;
do {
    $offset = 0;
    for ($i = 1; $i < 9; $i++) {
        if ($surveysCount[$i] === $offset){
            $sel = $surveys[$i];
            $selection[] = $sel;
            $counter++;             
        }
    }
    $offset++;
    //echo $selection;
} while ($counter < 1);
// clean up connections
mysql_close($conn);
$whichSurveyNr = mt_rand(1, $counter);
$which = $selection[$whichSurveyNr-1];
$which = $path.$which.$pathPostfix;
  echo "wSrNr:";
    echo $whichSurveyNr;
echo "selection: ";
echo count($selection);
echo " which: ";
echo $which;
    foreach($selection as $k => $v)
        echo " sel: k: ".$k." v: ".$v;*/
header("Location: $which"); 
?>
```

Comment: Your counter is incremented inside a condition. If that condition is never satisfied, $counter will always be smaller than 1.

Comment: `if ($surveysCount[$i] === $offset){` is always `FALSE`.

Comment: can you share the error that you are getting?

Comment: do  print_r($surveysCount[$i])  before the if ($surveysCount[$i] === $offset){  Make sure you have what you think you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently always resetting offset within the loop. I don't know this is what you intend.

Try

```
$offset = 0;
do {

    for ($i = 1; $i < 9; $i++) {
        if ($surveysCount[$i] === $offset){
            $sel = $surveys[$i];
            $selection[] = $sel;
            $counter++;             
        }
    }
    $offset++;
    //echo $selection;
} while ($counter < 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use == not with ===,it will returns you always false

```
do {
     $offset = 0;
    for ($i = 1; $i < 9; $i++) {
        if ($surveysCount[$i] == $offset){
            $sel = $surveys[$i];
            $selection[] = $sel;
            $counter++;             
        }
    }
    $offset++;
    //echo $selection;
} while ($counter < 1);
```

Comment: Because he needs to increment counter, not decrement it. And he is incrementing it.

Comment: He needs to go above 0 for the loop to exit, decrementing the counter from 0  will not help that. Counter = 0, Counter -1 is still less < 1

Comment: Why will === always return false, both are ints

Comment: == will trace equals to,and === will trace identical to

Comment: Yes I understand that and both are ints so as long as they both have the same number ie as long as they == then they will also === your edit will make no difference unless one is not an int

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that $counter is being incremented.

Make sure `$surveysCount[$i] === $offset` always happens.